# Issue in pointer while writing to file. segmentation fault

Tags: c++11, pointers, struct, binary, segmentation-fault

I am trying to write sequence of bytes into a binary file.
Converting structures into binary and storing in a pointer, and increment the pointer with the same size, before that i hold the address of that pointer into another so at the end i can write whole data from start to end into the file.
here is a code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
struct OhlData_struct
{
        int volume;

}__attribute__((__packed__));

struct StrCar
{
     int PhoneNo;
     long Model;
}__attribute__((__packed__));
int main()
{
    StrCar Car;
    OhlData_struct header;
    char *Data=(char *)calloc(0,(sizeof(OhlData_struct) + (sizeof(StrCar) * 10)));
    char *temp;
    temp = Data;
    string filename = "mydatastream_binary.txt";
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open (filename.c_str(), ios::out | ios::binary);

    header.volume=123;
    memcpy(Data,(char*) &header, sizeof(struct OhlData_struct));
    Data += sizeof(struct OhlData_struct);
    int i=0;
    while(i <10)
    {
            Car.PhoneNo=101+i;
            Car.Model=1001+i;
            memcpy(Data,(char*) &Car, sizeof(struct StrCar));

            outfile_copy.write (Data, sizeof(StrCar));
            Data += sizeof(struct StrCar);
            i++;
    }

     outfile.write (temp, (sizeof(struct OhlData_struct) + (sizeof(struct StrCar) * 10)));
    cout << "\n\nFile writeing done\n\n";
```

## outfile.write gives "sagmentation fault";

can anyone tell how to write whole DATA into the file ? where do I need to change the code!!

Tried a lot, but still not able to get the exact binary data into file,
I am new to C++ and this pointers are out of my mind.

Comment: `xyz[]` is not a valid type to put in a map, and sentences like `myhash.first` etc make no sense whatsoever. It looks like you have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please explain your real problem without invoking any C++-specific terminology.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `std::map<abc, std::vector<xyz>>` ?